# Developing strength and ability, versus attrition

Tags: pain, gymnastics

I'd like to increase my strength and ability in more gymnastic areas of fitness, but I also don't want to have long-term pain, either now or when I'm older.

I've put my whole body weight on my wrist joints before, and I've had no long-term issues. And I see gymnasts with great strength in their wrists.

But I have had no facts to support whether I could develop my wrist strength for (as an example) regular handsprings, without causing longer-term attrition and pain.

I guess something that would help me understand would be anecdotal evidence of people not having long-term wrist issues, or even better some credible statistics.